# Vector Projection explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Please can someone explain why this is? I think I understand projection when it is a comparison of two vectors but below has 3.

Im revising and I am so slow.

The projection of the vector $$\begin{pmatrix} 3\\\ -2\\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$ onto the plane spanned by the vectors

$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\\ -1\\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\\ 1\\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\\ -2\\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Project your vector onto each of the two spanning vectors and add the results.

Comment: How about inner product

Comment: Do you mind showing me step by step please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two standard approaches here.

**Option 1:** We can use an orthonormal basis and add together the separate projections. Note that the vectors $v_1 = (0,-1,1)$ and $v_2 = (0,1,1)$ are already orthogonal; to make them "normal" (length 1), we need only divide each vector by its length. So, we get the orthonormal basis $u_1 = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(0,-1,1),u_2 = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(0,1,1)$.  The projection of the vector $v = (3,-2,1)$ is

$$
(v \cdot u_1)u_1 + (v \cdot u_2) u_2 = \\
\frac 3{\sqrt{2}} u_1 + \frac {-1}{\sqrt{2}}u_2 = \\
(0,-\frac 32,\frac 32) + (0,-\frac 12 ,-\frac 12) =\\ 
(0,-2,1).
$$

---

**Option 2:** If $A$ is the matrix with columns $v_1,v_2$, then the desired projection can be calculated as $[A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T]v$.

Comment: please can you describe why orthonormal basis is considered in your solution? What’s special about it and why is it useful in working out projection? This is useful thank you for teaching me.

Comment: @PeddiePooh Orthonormal bases are special because they allow us to get the projection onto a subspace (a "comparison" of many vectors) using only the individual projections onto the basis elements (using only comparisons with two vectors at a time). The same could be said about orthogonal bases, but when the basis is also orthonormal, we don't need to worry about dividing by a length.